# : Couldn't find a matching Java operation for WSDD operation "suma"

Tags: java, webservice

tengo mi clase java con el webservice
       package com.prueba;

```
    import javax.jws.WebMethod;
    import javax.jws.WebParam;
    import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(serviceName = "HolaMundo")
public class HolaMundo {

@WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
 public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
 return "Hello " + txt + " !";
 }

@WebMethod(operationName = "Suma")
 public String Suma(@WebParam(name = "num1") int numero, @WebParam(name = "num2") int num  ) {
 return "Suma total es "+(numero+num);
 }


}
```

Al buscar mi wsdl me sale el error del titulo.¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Lograste resolver el problema

Comment: no...sigo peleandome con ello

Comment: En el título, pones "suma" en minúscula, en el código aparece (en *operationName*) con la primera letra en mayúscula. ¿Es eso correcto? En todo caso el nombre del método debería empezar por minúscula (estándares de Java).